# No setter found for property * in class *

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control

OK, I haven't used Spring in a while, so I'm a little rusty. Not sure if I missed something in all of this or not. My appContext.xml for Spring states that 'no setter is found for property testBean in class com.ztp.spring.injection.TestBean.

Here is the appContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="myTestBean" class="com.ztp.spring.injection.TestBean" />

<bean id="myTestClass" class="com.ztp.spring.injection.TestClass">
    <property name="testBean" ref="myTestBean" />
</bean>
```

and here is the TestClass.java file in its entirety:

```
public class TestClass {
    TestBean testBean;

    public void setTestClass(TestBean testBean) {
        this.testBean = testBean;
    }

    public void fillBean() {
        testBean.setId(5);
        testBean.setTestAnimal("sheltie");
    }
}
```

I have another program that I worked on months ago, and its the same logic-wise, and it works. So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

If its already been answer or you need more info, just say so, I'd like to figure this out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Typo in the method name. What you meant is this:

```
public void setTestBean(TestBean testBean) {
    this.testBean = testBean;
}
```

You had `setTestClass`. This would violate the JavaBean [conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions).

Comment: Thank you!!! I guess its my own stinking fault for naming them so similar that I couldn't see the difference.

The problem was fixed, but as is with programing more popped up. Onward to fix them!

Comment: We've all made silly mistakes that have big consequences. Glad to help. But also, can a brother get an accept on here haha?

Answer (score 2):

The method name should match the property name for the bean:

```
public void setTestBean(TestBean testBean) {
```